# New Wordpress install causes 403 error on test page access

Tags: wordpress, centos

I just installed Wordpress but can't view the "Hello World" test page due to a permissions issue. I'm getting a 403 error. I can get into index.php (in the wp-admin folder) to modify the file, but when I click on the link to view it I get the 403. There is no .htaccess file in my Wordpress folder[see update below]. I'm not sure what permissions to change. I did chmod the permissions on the Wordpress folder to 755 but it had no effect. I did not do any sort of recursion on the chmod as I didn't want to do a blanket permissions change without knowing just what I was doing. What should the permissions be on the various Wordpress files and directories? I'm running a Centos 6 server.

Update:
I have added the following .htaccess file to the wordpress folder but still have the same problem.

```
#BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/www/wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/www/wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
#END WordPress
```

BTW, if you wish to vote me down, I understand your need but would appreciate a few words why. Thx.

UPDATE #2: 
I have check my permissions and my folders are at 755 and the files at 644, which is what they are supposed to be from the information I'm finding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this problem. I had to add this line to my .htaccess file. Now everything works:

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php